# How to create archives on Linux which support replacing/deleting files?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, archive

If one has a compressed archive with thousands files in it, what is the optimal way to delete/replace files in it from a shell script?

**tar** does not support replacing files in archive, and "decompress and compress again" way for replacing a single file in a large archive doesn't seem an optimal way.

**xz** as it seems doesn't support this option either.

**7z** is also not suitable for this task (man page for 7z doesn't recommend to use it for compressing individual files, only for compressing tar files, due to issues with preserving file owner/group info).

**pax** also doesn't have options for deleting/replacing files in archive.

Is there a common way on Linux for creating such archives from command line?

Comment: There is no optimal way, just several mediocre-to-bad ways.

Comment: why does it have to be an archive? if you need to delete/replace files, sounds like an archive is not the right way to go.

Comment: This problem is more general then you think, and also exists on every other platform. Once you compress multiple files into a single archive, removing one (or updating it) is an expensive operation (because you have to uncompress everything, perform the update or delete and then compress everything). Otherwise, it *isn't* a valid archive anymore.

Comment: i believe ye olde **zip** format compresses files individually, so you can add or remove them without recompressing the entire archive.  (which is why it's often popular for games and other resource bundles: you can decompress just one file at a time.)  but just like with 7z, you'll probably lose the file metadata.

Comment: @Elliott if a compressed archive is a row of concatenated compressed files, then it's possible to delete just a single file from the middle of the row.

Comment: @AlBerger Is it? Maybe in RAM.

Comment: @Pavel updating only changed files in an archive seems more fast and convenient way for usual regular backups.

Comment: @Elliott, if the archive header contains offsets for individual compressed files, then deleting files from the middle of the archive is trivial.

Comment: sorry, I don't get it. how is it faster and more convenient than having a dedicated place in the file system? you can use advanced methods of ZFS for creating snapshots, moving backups to different disks etc. it also supports compression.

Comment: @AlBerger No it isn't. Not once those byte are on a disk in a single file.

Comment: @Pavel, say one has to do a regular backup to compressed archive of a directory with 10 000 files from which only a few files change from time to time. Then it's faster to compress only a few changed files than to uncompress and compress all 10 000 files.

Comment: @Elliott, if you have a 3000 bytes array which contains 3 compressed files 1000 bytes each, then you can the last (third) thousand bytes move to the place of the second thousand and update the file offsets in the header. Thus you can delete a file from the archive without uncompressing anything.

Comment: @AlBerger Except the entire stream is usually compressed for better compression ratios. Only tar doesn't compress at all, and it doesn't support your option either.

Comment: @Elliot, yes tar doesn't compress, but it doesn't delete or replace uncompressed files in tarball which is even easier. This is due to the fact that tar initially worked with mag tapes. But why newer utilities doesn't support this option is beyond me.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should seriously consider using [ZFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS) or any other advanced file system. This will allow you to

- create incremental backups (via snapshots)
- modify files within backups
- manage everything via command line (cronjobs etc.)
- use compression
- move backups across devices
- use different RAID levels if you need more security

ZFS runs perfectly under Solaris, but there is already a stable port for Linux.

Comment: Thank you for the link. However, I asked specifically about archives because the archive files should be accessible also from Windows (they are actually stored on NTFS file system).

Comment: you can make the ZFS volumes accessible via NFS (which is more or less the regular way for file servers) or install a tool like zfs-win on the Windows machine

Comment: Seems like an even more overhead than uncompressing-compressing. More easier probably is to perform backup from Windows.